# Hermitian metrics/Swan-Serre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles

We should denote by $M$ a compact topological space and let it's continuous functionals to the complex numbers $\mathbf{C}$ be $C(M)$. By the Swan-Serre theorem there is bijective equivalence between the finitely generated projective modules over the $C(M)$ and finite dim vector bundles over $M$:
$$
V \longleftrightarrow \Gamma(V).
$$
We should now focus to Hermitian vector bundles over $M$; A pointwise inner product $\langle\cdot ,\cdot\rangle_M$ (varying continuously) on the fibers gives a **conjugate linear** map
$$
\langle\cdot ,\cdot\rangle: \Gamma(V) \times \Gamma(V) \to C(M).
$$
The map $\langle\cdot ,\cdot\rangle$ is also nondegenerate in both entry. Also the function $\langle f,f\rangle$ is a positive. Do we have a correspondence between nondegenerate **conjugate linear** maps, with $\langle f , f\rangle$ positive, and Hermitian metrics?

EDIT: However if I multiply my metric by a positive function $f \geq 0$ such that $f(p) = 0$ for $p \in M$. Then the
conjugate linear map
$$
\langle\cdot ,\cdot\rangle: \Gamma(V) \times \Gamma(V) \to C(M)
$$
is positive definite and non-degenerate. However the metric $fg$ is not positive definite at the point $p$.

Comment: Your scalar product should be complex antilinear in one variable. With that, the answer is yes, as it suffices to check this in a local chart, i.e. for a trivial vector bundle.

Comment: @Bertram: I edited to conjugate linear.

Comment: @Bertram:  What is a reference for this?

Comment: I think this should follow immediately from the fact that the Swan-Serre theorem gives a monoidal identification that respects the duality

Comment: @denis: I think it might not - see my edit. Thanks!